# Matrix with prime entries and largest possible determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, prime-numbers, determinant

Let $n\ge 1$ be a natural number. Arrange the first $n^2$ primes in a $n\times n$-matrix, such that the determinant becomes as large as possible.

- What is the largest possible determinant and which matrix has it ?

For $n=2$, we have $\pmatrix{7&3\\2&5}$ with determinant $29$, which is optimal.

For $n=3$, we have $\pmatrix{23&7&3\\5&19&13\\11&2&17}$ with determinant $6640$,
which is optimal.

For $n=4$, the best value I found is $\pmatrix{37&7&47&23\\17&19&11&53\\41&31&2&5\\3&43&29&13}$ with deteminant $4673460$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [A180128](https://oeis.org/A180128) in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).  You can do better for $n=4:$
$$
\pmatrix{53&11&23&13\\
17&47&29&3\\
7&5&43&37\\
19&31&2&41}=4868296>4673460.
$$

The fifth term is
$$
\pmatrix{89&41&23&2&53\\
31&97&29&47&11\\
59&13&79&61&7\\
37&19&5&83&67\\
3&43&71&17}=735725998504
$$
and the sixth term is
$$
\pmatrix{137&73&7&89&83&13\\
79&139&67&19&3&97\\
101&5&149&61&37&53\\
2&109&103&71&113&11\\
59&29&41&17&131&127\\
23&47&43&151&31&107}=11305600374272.
$$

The seventh term is believed to be 35954639671827332, and the eighth term is between 154665569137423060000 and 154715716383037989022.

The terms were found by Hugo Pfoertner using [tabu search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabu_search). The upper bound is due to [Gasper, Pfoertner, & Sigg (2009)](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article1119.html?sid=1119).

Comment: Unbelievable, that OEIS contains this sequence. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter: It's always worth searching!